# Replacing part of code with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

How can I replace a ClassName in the code below, with a variable.

I have:

```
(function (root, factory) {

  factory((root.ClassName= {})); 

  dragged =[].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName'));

 });
```

How can I replace where i have the ClassNames with a variable like this:

```
 (function (root, factory) {

   var x = ClassName

   factory((root.ClassName= {})); 

   dragged =[].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName'));

 });
```

Note that it is only a part of the code I have, I do not need to change the code, I just need to call a variable where those classnames are appearing.

Comment: `var x = "ClassName"; factory((root[x]={}));` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for something like this?

```
function (root, factory) {
  var x = "ClassName";
  factory((root[x]= {}));
  dragged = [].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName(x));
};
```

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working. Here is the whole function, would you take a look? https://jsfiddle.net/c4n7xvhc/

Comment: why are you accessing _every_ property using bracket notation?

Comment: Thanks it worked, I mistakenly placed it inside the first function, it is working after i placed the var outside of the function.